# What is the right way to upgrade netty and its components for security reason?

Tags: spring-boot, security, rx-netty

Our spring boot (cloud) application uses rx-netty, whose version is `0.4.20`. And it sets netty and its components to version `4.1.5.Final`.

Currently our security auditing system found that the current netty-codec version (`4.1.52.Final`) is vulnerable and suggested us to upgrade to version `4.1.68+`.

I tried to lock `netty-codec` in pom.xml to `4.1.68.Final`, but then I found that other netty components like `netty-buffer` or `netty-handler` still stay at `4.1.52`.

I want to know:

- Should I keep all the netty components at the same version?
- What is the right way to upgrade individual vulnerable components?

Thanks

### Update:

`mvn dependency:tree`

```
...
[INFO] +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-contexts:jar:0.4.20:compile
[INFO] +- io.reactivex:rxnetty-servo:jar:0.4.20:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.netflix.servo:servo-core:jar:0.12.21:runtime
[INFO] +- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.4.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.69.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.69.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.52.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.52.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.52.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.69.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.52.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.69.Final:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.52.Final:runtime
...
```

Answer (score 4):

*Note that*: Spring boot version `2.5.5` uses netty `4.1.68.Final`, so you should be OK if you upgrade `spring-boot-starter-parent` to `2.5.5`

That being said:

How I upgrade to a higher/lower version of a dependency in spring-boot:

- have a look at the properties configured in `spring-boot-dependencies`
- change that property in my pom.xml with the wanted version

In your case, add `netty.version:4.1.69.Final` to your properties:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <netty.version>4.1.69.Final</netty.version>
        
    </properties>
```

---

### UPDATE:

When using `<netty.version>4.1.69.Final</netty.version>` with `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.2.10.RELEASE`, ref Gist [netty-upgrade](https://gist.github.com/dirkdeyne/6f71d4d331af20a7809588b7faf54884)

when you execute `mvn dependency:tree` you can see that every netty dependency is upgraded to `4.1.69.Final`

*output filtered on 'netty'*

```
    Regel 1: [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:tree (default-cli) @ netty-upgrade ---
    Regel 2: [INFO] com.example:netty-upgrade:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    Regel 25: [INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.2.10.RELEASE:compile
    Regel 26: [INFO] |  |  +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.9.12.RELEASE:compile
    Regel 26: [INFO] |  |  +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.9.12.RELEASE:compile
    Regel 27: [INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 27: [INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 28: [INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 28: [INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 29: [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 29: [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 30: [INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 30: [INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 42: [INFO] +- io.reactivex:rxnetty:jar:0.5.1:runtime
    Regel 44: [INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 44: [INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 45: [INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 45: [INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 46: [INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 46: [INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 47: [INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 47: [INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 48: [INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 48: [INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 49: [INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 49: [INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 50: [INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 50: [INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 51: [INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.69.Final:runtime
    Regel 51: [INFO] |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.69.Final:runtime
    Regel 52: [INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
    Regel 52: [INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.69.Final:compile
```

So, if you still have references to an other version, use `mvn dependency:tree` to see where that reference comes from.

Comment: We are using Spring boot 2.2.10 in our production, upgrading to 2.5.5 is a little bit risky.
And I have already changed <netty.version> to 4.1.69, but like what I described in the question, not all netty components upgraded to 4.1.69, still some of them stay at 4.1.52

Comment: Using `spring-boot:2.2.10.release` + `netty.version:4.1.69.Final` looks OK for me; gist here: [netty-upgrade](https://gist.github.com/dirkdeyne/6f71d4d331af20a7809588b7faf54884)

Comment: I have updated my question. It seems releated to rxnetty version, mine is 0.4.20, yours is 0.5.1, but I don't want to upgrade rxnetty either (because it is a huge move for now)

Comment: Even if I use `rxnetty:0.4.20`, all netty dependencies have the 4.1.69.Final version... Maybe you should share your pom.xml

Comment: I think I found the cause, we have a `spring-boot-dependencies`@2.2.10 in `<dependencyManagement>` which depends on `netty-bom@4.1.52.Final`. But the weird thing still is we cannot just use `<netty.version>` to overwrite this.
Finally, we use another `netty-bom` in root pom.xml to overwrite the one brought by `spring-boot-dependencies`

Comment: For netty.version:4.1.90.Final , what is the Spring Boot version i have to use? What is the version of netty supported by  Spring boot 2.6.9 support?